# VB6 exe error 'Invalid Picture'

Tags: windows, vb6

This is a bit of a grey-area question, so I'll try both here and Server Fault...

I have a utility app, built with VB6. I no longer have source for the app. The utility was last used successfully on Sunday morning. When attempting to run the app this morning, I get an error dialog complaining about 'Invalid Picture'. On a second and third server, the app works as intended.

The install of the app has not changed. As I don't have full control over the server, it is possible patches have been applied I am not aware of. Anyone know of a possible change to the OS that may have precipitated this error? The Server is running 2003 R2, SP1.

Comment: I have a customer that has started to experience this issue today on Win 2003 Server - did you manage to fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Best guess

- get yourself [Sysinternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)
- use it to check if your VB6 program loads some picture files
- if you found them, check if one of those picture files has a 32 bit depth (VB6 does only support 24bit depth at maximum, according to [this forum](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=540948))

Comment: I'll check out the Process Monitor, might help. However...the app in question hasn't changed recently, why would it all of a sudden complain about pictures now?

Comment: I could only speculate. There might be a dozen different reasons. So IMHO the only way to find out is a thorough analysis of your special case.